# What is the impact of argument n in numpy.fft.fft

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I would like to apply `fft` to my time series data to extract the lowest 5 dominant frequency components for predicting the y value (bacteria count) at the end of each time series. My code is as below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/df.csv', sep=',') 
X = df.iloc[0:2,0:10000]

dft_X = np.fft.fft(X)     # What should I fill in for argument n?
print(dft_X) 
print(len(dft_X))
plt.plot(dft_X)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

for i in dft_X: 

    m = i[np.argpartition(i,5)[:5]]
    n = i[np.argpartition(i,range(5))[:5]]

print(m,'\n',n)
```

In the `scipy` doc on `numpy.fft.fft`, it states that

> numpy.fft.fft(a, n=None, axis=-1, norm=None)
>
> ...
>
> n : int, optional
>
> Length of the transformed axis of the output. If n is smaller than the length of the input, the input is cropped. If it is larger, the input is padded with zeros. If n is not given, the length of the input along the axis specified by axis is used.

But I am still not clear about the effect of argument n value on the output and how to decide what value to use.

I notice that when `n = 10`, the output is as follows:

```
# n= 10
# [-1.5       -1.11022302e-16j -0.46352549-1.42658477e+00j
#  -1.21352549-8.81677878e-01j -1.21352549+8.81677878e-01j
#  -0.46352549+1.42658477e+00j] 
#  [-1.5       -1.11022302e-16j -1.21352549-8.81677878e-01j
#  -1.21352549+8.81677878e-01j -0.46352549-1.42658477e+00j
#  -0.46352549+1.42658477e+00j]
```

and when `n = 10000`, the output is as follows:

```
# n= 10000
# [-4752.15448944 +4113.44846878j -5199.36419709 -1826.78753048j
#  -4659.45705354-13014.97971229j -4752.15448944 -4113.44846878j
#  -5199.36419709 +1826.78753048j] 
#  [-5199.36419709 -1826.78753048j -5199.36419709 +1826.78753048j
#  -4752.15448944 -4113.44846878j -4752.15448944 +4113.44846878j
#  -4659.45705354-13014.97971229j]
```

What determines the right n value to use? Besides, why are output values complex numbers? Any help is appreciated.

Here is the time series plot for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I am still not clear about the effect of argument n value on the output and how to decide what value to use.

For "n = size of input", the result is the plain discrete fourier transform: it represents the signal of duration (T = n dt) exactly in frequency space. The lowest frequency component is a sine/cosine of wave period 2T.

For "n > size of input", you perform the transform of a signal that is the original one with zeros appended. The lowest frequency that can be represented corresponds thus to a longer wave period 2T. The signal is thus cut abruptly to zero. Depending on the input signal this may introduce unwanted higher frequency components.

For "n < size of input", you truncate the signal. If you have a "stationary signal", it could make sense to analyze shorter samples (possibly with windowing).

> What determines the right n value to use?

It depends on the application and on the sampling (very long stationary series, short measurement, ...). Unless you have some reason to use the option, you can omit n.

> Besides, why are output values complex numbers?

A Fourier transform of a real signal is complex in general. It is real only for even signals.

You can play with FFTs with simple signals such as a pure sine or cosine to make sense of this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. May I ask some further questions? Regarding second highlight: What do you mean by "very long stationary series", as in constant mean/variance? And "short measurement"? Since I only want to get the main pattern of the time series by extracting the lowest 5 dominant frequency components for predicting the y value, do you reckon that I'd better omit n? Regarding third highlight: I am a bit concerned about using complex number features in model training. Do theses numbers represent frequencies?

Comment: Comment continued: I've posted a plot for my time series data(water temp against time) for your reference.I think it might be irrelevant to classify them as even/odd signal given their unique shape? As you can see, most of the outputs are complex numbers. If I were to use them as features, do you have any advice/suggestions regarding dealing with complex numbers? For instance, is there a valid alternative way to extract the main patterns(eg. frequency/amplitude) of the time series? Thank you very much!

Comment: "very long stationary": yes, cst mean and variance. Like the Ornstein Uhlenbeck process, or a data channel with noise and you are interested in the noise. This is apparently not your case. Automatic computation of the main frequency can be a sensitive task, however. Regarding the complex numbers, you should look up "power spectrum". It is the "squared norm" of the transform and what you should use for frequency detection.

Comment: Regarding the pattern matching, there are practical details such as smoothing that will make it more robust.

Comment: @nilsinelabore: "do you reckon that I'd better omit n?" Yes, don't use the `n` parameter unless you have a good reason to do so and understand the consequences. Setting `n` dictates which frequencies you can measure. A very small `n` makes it so that you can measure only very high frequencies. Note that the data is truncated to `n` samples before applying the transform. What do the first `n` samples of your data say about the signal you are trying to characterize? Can you still see the pattern of interest?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for your comment. May I ask what you mean by "first n samples of your data "? For most of the cases time data points are at 25°C and only experience fluctuations when the tap is being activated as shown in the graph, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @CrisLuengo In the question, I demonstrated outputs for 2 rows of data(time series) as examples. But realised they are complex numbers, I am a bit unsure how to apply to logistic regression to see the pattern of interest..